# How do I get rid of this bizarre visual glitch when opening File Explorer in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I've recently bought a new HP workstation. It came with Windows 10 Pro, but I naturally installed my own copy (latest ISO from Micosoft) over it to get a fresh machine.

Every time I open File Explorer, for example by double-clicking the "tmp" folder on my desktop, it has this very annoying visual glitch which is perceived by my eyes as a bright white "flash", as if it doesn't apply/"paint" the dark theme until several frames of drawing a white background.

(It may sound like a minor thing, but it's seriously driving me insane, especially as I have a huge text file full of unanswered questions to other problems...)

Eventually, I decided to video-record the screen and go through the resulting video frame-by-frame. Indeed, it *does* have a definite visual glitch -- in fact, multiple ones. This is, frame by frame, what happens when I open File Explorer:

[Frame 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdQqT.png)

[Frame 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wlyi9.png)

[Frame 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3qpU.png)

[Frame 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guaQZ.png)

[Frame 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkzm3.png) (red rectangle added by me for privacy reasons)

Insane, isn't it? I have checked the installed video drivers and they match the latest ones both on HP's product page for this computer as well as NVIDIA's site. I simply have the right, updated drivers. It's not that.

(Besides, I frankly don't even understand how this could happen even if I for some reason had 18-year-old drivers.)

Does anyone know what is causing this? And how to solve it? It really feels "cheap" and angers me constantly because it feels like I'm using a badly set up garbage machine instead of this finely-tuned, carefully installed and brand new computer.

"Sending it back" and any such advice is completely out of the question for numerous important reasons (privacy, security, practicality, downtime, etc.).

Would be really nice to get this solved, or at least *explained*, once and for all!

PS: I'm not registered and can thus not reply if you have further questions. This site doesn't make that very clear. I hope that I have provided all relevant details.

Comment: You really should register your account, allowing you to edit your question, and respond to feedback about your question.  Of course, even as a guest you can do that, provided you don't log out of your active session.

Comment: Installing over manufacturer-supplied operating system can be problematic. How can we know what you lost? I suggest resetting Windows, in the hope that this will reinstall the original Windows version. If the problem is then fixed, come back here for instructions on doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

- Assuming you didn't download any drivers yourself and let windows update download the drivers for you, I suggest that you again do a clean install of windows 10 v1903, and then download and install the drivers yourself from HP website(including graphics drivers).
- Before doing such, you could try to toggle back to light theme and restarting your PC and then switching back to dark theme.
- Uninstall the graphics drivers and then again install the graphics drivers downloaded from HP website(check if they have specifically for v1903).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try one of these:

Option-1:
Create a new Windows user account, sometime drivers and user profiles can get corrupted when shifting themes.  It's happened to me before, and this fixed it. :)

Option-2:
1. Download and run CCleaner,
2. Install all Win-10 updates, reboot, and repeat,
3. Go to Device Manager, and uninstall the display driver. This should bring you to the default VGA windows driver,
4. Obtain the chipset brand for your GPU, and download the newest driver,
5. Install driver,
6. Ensure refresh rate is set to at least 60mhz or 75mhz,
7. Try setting color depth to either 8 or 16bit,
8. Reboot.

Options-3:
Trying using a different video output port on your PC, cable, and monitor port.

Option-4:
Try a different monitor.

Option-5:
Obtain a separate PCIe video card and see if the glitch goes away.

I hope one of these suggestions helps you. :)